# "\n" not working with "time" in Python2

Tags: python, python-2.7, time, printing

When I use this code in `Python2.7`:

```
print("-----------")
print("\nTime is: \n")
print("-----------")
```

I have a regular output like this

```
-----------

Time is:

-----------
```

But if I use time I have a wrong output. Code:

```
import time

start = time.time()

print("-----------")
print("\nTime is: ", (time.time() - start))
print("-----------")
```

Output:

```
-----------
('\nTime is: ', 0.0)
-----------
```

Why this happens?

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: Your first code does not output what you say

Comment: @Hyperion you are using Python2 , no? if yes, clarify it because it works well in python3.

Comment: Yes Python 2.7.9. Edited the message, now the code print what i say

Comment: @Hyperion, great, you may choose an accepted answer if it is working for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you are using `Python2`, so just write:

```
print "\nTime is: ", (time.time() - start)
```

In `Python2`, `print` is a statement so `print(,)` is considered as printing `tuple`: `print (,)`.

Comment: `print("a",5)` vs `print "a",5`

Answer (score 2):

In python2, `print` is a statement, unless you enable the new print function with:

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

So, `print("\nTime is: ", (time.time() - start))` is actually the `print` statement printing a tuple. Either use the above `__future__` import, or get rid of the parentheses:

```
print "\nTime is: ", (time.time() - start)
```

Or use python3, where `print` is always a function. :)